# Mouse Move and ViewController

Tags: swift, cocoa, viewcontroller

In order to understand the basic concepts I develop a simple Mac OS X application to calculate fractals. The application is a simple window app and has a class that calculate the fractal, and a single window in which there are:

1. a custom view for showing the  image.
2. some controls for select calculation parameters. These controls are
   connected with the appdelegate.

Everything works fine, but :

1. I would like that when the mouse is over the view with the image,
       some text fields report in real time the coordinates. What i have to
       do to realize that ?
2. I suppose that the connection I have done with the app delegate
       is not the best solution.

Is it better to define a custom view controller? If so, how can I do to introduce a custom viewcontroller using interface builder?

Comment: Try to format this question in a more readable way. Maybe some enumerated lists of points like "1)" or "A)" would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can just track the Mouse Events MouseMoved

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW1

Then you might be able to do this:

```
NSPoint location = [renderView convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
```

Then you will get X and Y relative to the view containing the image.

be careful of reading the apple documentation or you might miss things like:

> Note: Because mouse-moved events occur so frequently that they can
>   quickly flood the event-dispatch machinery, an NSWindow object by
>   default does not receive them from the global NSApplication object.
>   However, you can specifically request these events by sending the
>   NSWindow object an setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents: message with an
>   argument of YES.

Comment: Many Thanks!

Works fine, but i had to add a new ViewController.